# Nested Mapping using MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct, object-object-mapping

```
class Identifier {
    private long id;
    private String type;
    private List<Status> statuses;
}     

class Customer {
    private Identifier identifier;
}

class CustomerProfile {
    private Customer customer;
}

class CustomerIdentifierDO {
    private long id;
}

class CustomeDO {
    private CustomerIdentiferDO custID;

}

class CustomerProfileDO {
    private String category;
    private List<Status> custStatuses;
    private CustomeDO customer;
}

@Mapper
public interface CustomerProfileMapper {
    CustomerProfile toCustomerProfile(CustomerProfileDO profileDO) ;  
    Customer   toCustomer(CustomerDO customerDO);
    Identifier toIdentifier(CustomerIdentifierDO identifierDO);

}
```

Everything works fine till this. Now I want to map `custStatuses`, `category` of `CustomerProfileDO` class to `statuses` and `type` of `Identifier` class. I've no idea how to supply `CustomerProfileDO` object to `toIdentifier` mapping method, so that I can include the mapping there itself. I tried following

```
@Mappings({
     @Mapping(target = "customer.identifier.type", source = "category")
})
CustomerProfile   toCustomerProfile(CustomerProfileDO profileDO) ;
```

But this nested mapping is overriding all the mapping config of below method. That should not happen.

`toIdentifer(CustomerIdentifierDO identifierDO)`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently MapStruct can pass source parameters to single methods. In order to achieve what you are looking for (without using nested target types you would need to use something like `@AfterMapping`. It can look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface CustomerProfileMapper {
    CustomerProfile toCustomerProfile(CustomerProfileDO profileDO) ;  
    Customer   toCustomer(CustomerDO customerDO);
    Identifier toIdentifier(CustomerIdentifierDO identifierDO);

    @AfterMapping
    default void afterMapping(@MappingTarget CustomerProfile profile, CustomerProfieDO profileDO) {
        Identifier identifier = profile.getCustomer().getIdentifier();
        identifier.setStatus(profileDO.setStatus());
        identifier.setType(profileDO.setCategory());
    }    
}
```